# Two hashmap to entity class

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have two `HashMap` I want to de-serialize to entity class using GSON.

```
void convert(){
    HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("key1","value1");
    map1.put("key2","value2");
    HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("key3","value3");
    map2.put("key4","value4");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String service = gson.toJson(map2);
    map1.put("service", service);
    String json = gson.toJson(map1);
    MyModel myModel = gson.fromJson(json, MyModel.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(myModel));
}
```

My entity class

```
 public class MyModel {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    String service;
    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }
    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }
    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }
    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }
    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Is there any efficient approach to do it.

Comment: If you want to create json from map, why you are using `MyModel` ?

Comment: What you want clear in your question, what is your input and what is you output . Means you MyModel from json ? or Map to json ?

Comment: `service` can be another `POJO` class. Or even you can declare it as `Map`. It totally depends on your requirement.

Comment: make service a hashmap and it will work

Comment: `I want involve entity class` Why you want to involve the entity class ? Are you want both map to json and map to Entity class ?

Comment: Actually i want  hashmap to map into entity class so can get required json

Comment: First of all you don't need to use enity class to get the gson you expected. You can directly convert map to json

Comment: Directly i can convert to json using GSON but i want entity class how can i do that

Comment: Don't change the question completely, you can add your updated code and ask, the way you are doing it will not help the future reader

Comment: No i realize later there is unnecessarily  converting to json then pojo so i want it to be direct HashMap to pojo. suggest any way to do it please @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks

Answer (score 1):

You can directly convert HashMap to json

```
HashMap<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("key1","value1");
map1.put("key2","value2");
HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("key3","value3");
map2.put("key4","value4");
 
map1.put("service", map2);
String result = gson.toJson(map1);
```

And if you want convert json to Entity class

```
MyModel myModel = gson.fromJson(result, MyModel.class);
```

And use `Map<String,String>` for service field

```
public class MyModel {
    String key1;
    String key2;
    Map<String,String> service;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note: OP update his code in the question